# how to get ssh to use a different id_dsa

Tags: ssh, key

How can I convince that id_dsa is not stored in ~/.ssh when connecting to one particular host.

The obvious question is why. The answer is this key is more sensitive and needs to be password protected while the other is used for automation.

While this is not a programming problem, I would not be surprised to learn this requires a programming solution.

Comment: The only reason I'll argue this is programming related is that many SCM tools use ssh as part of their method of action to work, and SCM tools are certainly programming related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.ssh/config`, set something like:

```
Host somehost
     IdentityFile /path/to/extra_secret_key
```

I have one host that has `IdentityFile` set to `~/.ssh/iddsa_aux`, but the parameter should accept any path name.

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find. You wouldn't believe how close I came to making a second copy of ssh and modifying it with a hexeditor.

Answer (score 12):

Theres a handy trick you can use to make it really easy, oddly, I just discussed this 30 minutes ago with a friend.

*~/.ssh/config*

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ident/%r@%h
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

This makes it really easy to use a fallback pattern, as the options are run through top to bottom.

Then to specify a specific key for "Bob@someHost" you just have to create the file

```
~/.ssh/ident/Bob@someHost
```

And it will try that first when logging into that host.

If the file cannot be found, or the key is rejected, it will try the next one, in this case,

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The benefit of this technique is you don't have to add a new entry every time you add another host, all you have to do is create the keyfile in the right place and it does the rest automatically.

Answer (score 2):

From the ssh man page:

```
 -i identity_file
         Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or
         DSA authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
         protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for pro-
         tocol version 2.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-
         host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have
         multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in config-
         uration files).
```